# What is the risk and impact of turning off KPTI?

Tags: kernel, security

KPTI brings with it a performance hit. For the average Ubuntu (non-Windows, non-wine) user using their laptop behind a home or office firewall, is there any significant risk of exploitation by Spectre or Meltdown when KPTI is turned off?

E.g. some Linux users don't install an anti-virus package because computer viruses are [much rarer on Linux than on Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus). Is a user more likely to encounter a Spectre or Meltdown exploitation than a Linux virus?

Please answer this using a cost-
benefit analysis not just an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a look but only get an impression of a theoretical risk. I have edited my question to compare to risk of Linux viruses.

Comment: As right now the risk is probably small as it would take a while for crackers to leverage the exploit. You really need to read a quality review article about this - https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/jan/04/meltdown-spectre-computer-processor-intel-security-flaws-explainer . There will be a delay, and then the cracking tools will script this exploit and it will be a large problem for unpatched systems. As with any security decision, how much do you value your data ? How much , if any, of a performance hit is the fix for your CPU ? Is keeping your bank account worth the slow down ?

Comment: I think this is an excellent cost/benefit analysis question and was considering answering it with **KAISER** and **KASLR** references. But with 4 close votes so far hours spent answering seems like a waste of time.

Comment: I don't see that answers to this have to be primarily opinion based. It is possible as WinEunuuchs2Unix says to do a cost benefit analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we go to hard facts, let me voice my opinion that your comparison between viruses and exploits for Spectre and Meltdown are a bit skewed: there are >1 million viruses out there and no exploits for Spectre and Meltdown at the time of this writing: only Proof of Concept (PoC) code, but the NSA, CIA,BSI, ФСБ and other three-letter organisations are very probably running overtime now to come up with exploits.

Secondly, risk cannot be taken into account all by itself without talking about impact as well, so that's why I added that to your question.

Now onto the hard facts:

- Today the number of exploits is 0 (as far was we know), **so the risk is low**.
  (Cost: high. Benefit: Low)
- In the future, the number of exploits will increase, **so the risk will increase linearly.**
  (Cost: High. Benefit: Medium.)
- If you would decide not to implement the patches, and you would be hit by an exploit in the future, **the impact will be high as this is a [side-channel vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack)**
  (Cost: High. Benefit: High)
- If you would be running in a virtual environment with Ubuntu as the host system, **the impact would be very high** as the VMs on the same physical host would be able to inspect each other's memory...
  (Cost: High. Benefit: Extremely High)

Comment: If you run in a Cloud environment the Meltdown / Spectre vulnerability should be patched in the Cloud systems OS primrly, I think, as the OS in the vm don't have direct access to hardware.

Comment: @SorenA yes, correct: at the hypervisor level, but as the OP did not specify that in its question and other people might be reading this question while running in such an environment, I've added that scenario just to be rigorously complete.

Comment: @SorenA **Incorrect**.  In VMs, a *virtual* CPU has its own firmware and such.  The OSes therefore still need patched in the Cloud environment, so taht more than just the 'host' is patched, as the virtual CPUs exposed to the guests could potentially be exploited in a similar way.  This has been confirmed and accepted within the Internet Security community.

Comment: Thanks, this is great Fabby but would you be able to compare cost benefit roughly with not installing antivirus software eg. if infected by a typical Linux virus is the impact the same or higher? Will the number of exploits increase at a greater rate than Linux viruses? What is the performance impact of running antivirus software? Etc. This will make it easier to quantify the costs and benefits.

Comment: It's not a Black&White world out there: it all depends on how many kernel calls you make per second and that is why the numbers vary so widely from a 3% slowdown for simple desktop use up to 25% slowdown for database servers, so to quantify the above, I'd have to measure a statistically significant portion of all Ubuntu Servers out there before and after the patch was applied and then extrapolate to the entire Ubuntu Universe.  I'm pretty sure Canonical could do it if someone were to pay them to undertake such a task but from an Ask Ubuntu perspective, I don't have access to that data...

Comment: Hi Fabby, quantify was perhaps too strong a word. I meant do the same Cost: xxx, Benefit: xxx for Linux viruses to allow comparing Benefit of KPTI vs Benefit of using antivirus software.

Comment: Better than Hi-Med-Lo you will not get on a simple Q&A site like Ask Ubuntu.  If you want more, you'd have to contact Canoncal, the company behind Ubuntu and pay them money for hard numbers. Also, please don't forget to press the little grey check-mark to accept the answer as valid, which is the only payment I require if this answer helped you.  **:-) :-) :-)**

Comment: @SorenA: Answer edited to make it clearer what i meant.

Comment: Fabby I have chosen your answer as the accepted one, but think you have misunderstood what I was suggesting as an improvement. I was merely suggesting a comparison be done with antivirus eg. for viruses:

Comment: "Today the number of viruses is less than 50 (as far was we know), so the risk is low/medium/high.
(Cost: low/medium/high. Benefit: low/medium/high).
In the future, the number of viruses will increase, so the risk will increase linearly/exponentially/whatever.
(Cost: low/medium/high. Benefit: low/medium/high)
If you would decide not to install antivirus, and you would be hit by a virus in the future, the impact will be low/medium/high.
(Cost: low/medium/high. Benefit: low/medium/high)."

This would make understanding the cost benefit easier IMHO.

Comment: Drop by in [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com) and ping me there @fabby because this is more for an extended discussion which is frowned upon here as we're looking for clear well-defined questions with clear well-defined answers instead of extended discussions. Favour returned: Question upvoted. **:-)**